# Updating/overwriting HTML data with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html

I am trying to loop through response data and insert values them into the HTML of my webpage, the HTML might already contain some values so I want to clear them and insert only the new ones so it is up to date.

My HTML code looks like this;

```
<div id="ind">
  {% for inf in prospect.prospect_industries.all %}
    {% if inf.is_interested %}
      <div>
        <span id="industryInterest" data-fit="id_industry{{inf.id}}"></span>

        <p>{{inf.get_industry_display}}</p>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My JS looks like this:

```
 for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) { 
   //alert(response[i].industry + ":" + response[i].is_interested);

   if (response[i].is_interested) {

     $("#industryInterest").html(response[i].industry);
     $("#industryInterest").attr("data-fit", response[i].industry);
   }
 }
```

I tried to do something like this

```
$('#ind').html('');
```

however, that removes the HTML within the #ind div so then I am not able to insert the new values. What is the correct approach to update the HTML in this case? Do I first clear the HTML of the #ind div and then recreate it from jQuery?

### EDIT:

I managed to get this working using the following code:

```
$('#industryInterest').html("");

  for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    if (response[i].is_interested) {
      $("#industryInterest").append("<p>" + response[i].industry + "</p>");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Using same id for multiple elements is not allowed.

Comment: And your `$("#industryInterest")` returns first div with such id. If you look more careful you'll see that contents of first div are changing.

Comment: You should you use a class instead of id.

Comment: @u_mulder yes, you are right, the contents of the first div are changing but not the others, I would for them to all be cleared and the new values populated.

Comment: You don't need to clear the div, just use a class and then add `$(".[className]").html(response[i].industry);` replace [classname] with the class you use and it will work.

Comment: @A.J do you mean I replace the #ind id with class? And change my loop code to update the html with the code you added?

Comment: @user2573690 : Actually you also need to select  the div who's content you want to update. Look at u_moulder's answers it cover the stated point.

Answer (score 1):

So, as we learned - using same id for multiple elements is not allowed. Of course, you can add same ids, but your code

```
$("#industryInterest")
```

will select only **first** one.

That's why you need to use something else. Use a class `industryInterest`:

```
<span class="industryInterest" ....
```

Next, you want to update not all `span`s but ones which are `is_interested`. For getting element with certain index use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

So, your code becomes:

```
for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) { 
   //alert(response[i].industry + ":" + response[i].is_interested);

   if (response[i].is_interested) {
     // we use class here and we're getting 
     // element with the same index as i
     // and you can chain jquery functions too!
     $(".industryInterest").eq(i)
         .html(response[i].industry)
         .attr("data-fit", response[i].industry);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the changes you mentioned above but I the HTML is still not updated for me. Basically what happens is I have a modal with a list of checkboxes, I select or unselect some and click save. The right values get saved to my database but the right values are not displayed on the webpage, they are not updated based on the selection on the modal unless I refresh the page.

Comment: Do a debug. Check value of `$(".industryInterest").eq(i)` on each iteration.

Comment: The value depends on what I selected, if I marked 3 checkboxes the first 3 iterations have data the rest are undefined because the checkboxes were unmarked?

Comment: I don't know how your `response` is generated. What exactly is undefined?

Comment: My response will contain objects which have the attributes industry and is_interested. Basically for each industry it will say true or false if the user selected the checkbox or not, the checkbox value is saved in is_interested. So what I want to do is update the HTML with only the industries the user is interested in. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. I provided code for you according to this assumption. So, what is wrong with it, can you explain?

Comment: When I mark a checkbox on the modal and click save, the industry that I marked does not get updated on the webpage. If I unmark a checkbox, it does not remove it from the webpage. The correct values are stored in the database because if I refresh the page the correct values are displayed. Its just that I want to update the webpage HTML without having to refresh, the code does not do that, nothing happens to the HTML when I click save on the modal.

Comment: Listen, I don't see any of events happening on your side. So I can't say what is wrong there. All I know that my code is enough for checking what values to change. Please check your `response` iteration and find if something is wrong there.

Comment: No, I don't have one. You have to solve it yourself. Check fiddle and see what is wrong with your code.

Comment: I managed to get it working, but using a different approach than what you mentioned. Is there any reason why I shouldn't use the approach in my edit on the original post?

Comment: So you still use one `id` for all? Okaaaaay,